# Using datepick function inside another datepick function

Tags: jquery, validation, date, datepicker

I am having two date picker. If first date is selected as 20 February, then the second date picker's maximum date should be February 20. How to make this work. I am using keith-wood js. This is my code.

```
$("#campusOnDate").datepick({ 
onSelect: function(dates) { 
    var campusOnDate = document.getElementById('campusOnDate').value;
            var firstIndex = campusOnDate.indexOf("-");
            var secondIndex = campusOnDate.lastIndexOf("-");
            var d1 = campusOnDate.substring(0, firstIndex);
            var m1 = campusOnDate.substring(firstIndex + 1, secondIndex);
            var y1 = campusOnDate.substring(secondIndex + 1, campusOnDate.length);
            campusOnDate = m1 + "-" + d1 + "-" + y1;
            var date1 = new Date();
            var date2 = new Date(campusOnDate);
            var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
            var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
            $('#closingDate').datepick({
            maxDate: +diffDays, showTrigger: '#calImg'});
} });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation [here](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.HTML) (Date range with separate fields) shows how to perform a filter using two dates, using a range in the format start-end.

Code:

```
$('#startPicker,#endPicker').datepick({ 
    onSelect: customRange, showTrigger: '#calImg'}); 

function customRange(dates) { 
    if (this.id == 'startPicker') { 
        $('#endPicker').datepick('option', 'minDate', dates[0] || null); 
    } 
    else { 
        $('#startPicker').datepick('option', 'maxDate', dates[0] || null); 
    } 
}
```